# how do we increase our google analytics 50 properties limit?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

we are using google's api to create properties for analytics. we are quickly approaching our 50 property limit. how do we increase the limit?

we've been accepted to the beta program. the email redirects us to SO. is there a g+ group we can ask to increase our limit?

Comment: What Beta program is this you are referring to?

Comment: Google says "To raise this limit, please reach out to your account manager", which suggests that additional properties are available for GA Premium customers (with a standard GA account you do  not have an account manager, so your solution is, pay 150 000 USD per year to Google). By beta program you mean the beta for write access to the management API ?

Comment: Also, in addition to @EikePierstorff, if it's a Beta through Premium, then maybe you shouldn't mention that as it you should be under NDA.

Comment: we mean the beta for write access to the management API.